# Python - Stumbled upon "'DictReader' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, dictionary

I have no idea what this error is caused by, or how to fix it.

Basically, what I try to achieve is to read from a .csv file and make a dictionary from the information inside it.
I've done it before without any problems, but this time it's really weird.

```
#Read External Data
DataNames = os.listdir("Data")

#Import Classes
ClassesPath = os.path.join("Data", DataNames[1])
Classes = open(ClassesPath)
global ClassesDict
ClassesDict = csv.DictReader(Classes, delimiter=",")
```

Upon trying to run

```
print(ClassesDict)
```

or

```
print(ClassesDict["ID"])
```

it always give me the error:

```
TypeError: 'DictReader' object is not subscriptable
```

I do know that lists, dictionaries, etc. are subscriptable objects, but my variable "ClassesDict" **is** (or should be) a dictionary.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is that all your code? You're not showing where you're iterating over the `DictReader` to get the rows out of it... are you not doing that?

Comment: I, indeed, did not do that. I thought having the variable alone would work as is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class provides an iterable interface over the csv data source where items are dictionaries:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(Classes, delimiter=",")
for row in reader:
    print(row["ID"])
```